# Setting Cookie not working

Tags: php, cookies

Isn't this suppose to increment every time I load the page? Cause its not doing that its ending at `2` AND when I open other pages with the code in place it tells me that `$_COOKIE['count']` is not set.

```
if(!isset($_COOKIE['count'])){
    setcookie("count", 1, time() + 31536000);
} else {
    setcookie("count", $_COOKIE['count']++, time() + 31536000);
}
```

Ok so answers to the incrementing problem thanks its fixed +1's for you guys BUT the second problem is still there which is:

Ok so now its incrementing properly BUT problem 2 is still the same for 1 page e.g. index.php the cookie has a value of 15 when I go to the other page e.g. second.php the value is 5 when I refresh its 6 when I go back to index.php the value is 16. any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok so I had 2 problems in this. First is with the increment part (but I was just testing if the value was changing didn't really needed the increment part) AND the second one was the mix up between pages. . why different pages had different values that didn't stack. The answer to that problem was . . I didn't set a value for the `path parameter`, I didn't realize it was needed till then. I think it bugged up because of my `url rewrites` not sure though just a hunch. But anyway the path param fixed it for me.

If any of you get into the same trouble simply add a value to path param while setting your cookies like so:

> setcookie("cookiename", $cookievalue, $cookielifespan , '/');

If the path param  is set to `'/'` the cookie will be available within the entire domain

For more details just check the **[manual,](http://www.php.net/setcookie)** Cheers!

Answer (score 5):

Change `$_COOKIE['count']++` to either `$_COOKIE['count']+1` or `++$_COOKIE['count']`and the code will work perfectly.

Comment: Ok so now its incrementing properly BUT problem 2 is still the same for 1 page `e.g. index.php` the cookie has a value of `15` when I go to the other page `e.g. second.php` the value is `5` when I refresh its `6` when I go back to `index.php` the value is `16`. any ideas?

Comment: @Deadpool Are you visiting the pages with different browsers?

Comment: Nope same browser same domain.

Comment: @Deadpool Do you have the same code for `$_COOKIE['count']` in `index.php` and `second.php`?

Comment: @Deadpool I’m not sure why this is happening but you may create another PHP file with the code for `$_COOKIE['count']` and include that file to both `index.php` and `second.php`.

Comment: I made 2 new pages with the code above and its acting normally. Something must be tampering with the code to make the other pages act weird, I'm guessing similar variables. Anyway thanks for the help +1.

Answer (score 2):

```
$a = 1;
$b = $a++; //with the $a++ syntax, $b is set to $a's old value first, 
//and then $a is increased
//$b = 1, $a = 2

$a = 1;
$b = ++$a //with the ++$a syntax,  $a is incremented first 
//and then $b is set to (incremented) $a
//$b = 2, $a = 2
```

So, you need to do `++$_COOKIE['count']`, because you want to increase the cookie value before it is passed to setcookie.

Comment: Ok so now its incrementing properly BUT problem 2 is still the same for 1 page e.g. index.php the cookie has a value of 15 when I go to the other page e.g. second.php the value is 5 when I refresh its 6 when I go back to index.php the value is 16. any ideas?

Comment: Are both pages on the same exact domain?

Comment: Both pages are on the same domain and I'm browsing the pages on the same browser

Comment: That shouldn't be happening. Are you sure you are increasing the same cookie value?

Comment: Can you link to the page where this is happening?

Comment: I made 2 new pages with the code above and its acting normally. Something must be tampering with the code to make the other pages act weird, I'm guessing similar variables. Anyway thanks for the help +1.